# Reverse Geocoding, Nominatim, TIGER & residential house numbers

Tags: openstreetmap, tiger, reverse-geocoding, nominatim

Coming across [Nominatim/Installation](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation) it says:

> In the US, the OSM instance of Nominatim uses TIGER address data to complement the still sparse OSM house number data.

Basically I'm wonder how it works? Because:

1. In the [TIGER FTP](ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2016/2016_TL_Shapefiles_File_Name_Definitions.pdf) I can't find any file (.shp) representing points/polygons of buildings, not speaking about attribute of house number. By the way: where I can find polygon of regular residential building in TIGER?
2. Looking at the open street map ([example](http://www.openstreetmap.org/way/326312741)) I don't see a house number. Same when downloading the .shp from geofabric etc.
3. Checking in public [Nominatim API URL](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=37.75077&lon=-100.00643&zoom=18&addressdetails=1) there is a house number. So even if there is another source of data rather than TIGER - Why I don't see it on the open street map? Because if some part of the open street map project has the information - don't we should see it on the main map?
4. Even more - Sometimes the Nomination works fine even if unlike in the above example, we don't have polygon of the building at all on the map...

Comment: I think the tiger data has address number ranges on the road segments

Comment: @iant So let's say a road is 100m with number range 1-4, so if the lat/lon located on the 3'rd (50m-75m), it takes 3'rd from the range which in this case is 3?